# Weglassen eines Artikels nach einem "und"

Tags: article

Ist bei einem Satz nach Schema (hier Nominalstil)

> Konflikt als Folge der Expansionspolitik und *der* Aufrüstung Chinas

das zweite *"der"* unwichtig oder grammatikalisch notwendig?

Comment: Mein Eindruck ist, es hängt ein bisschen vom Kontext ab. Ist das die Schlagzeile einer Zeitungsnachricht? Ist es eine Kapitelüberschrift in einem Buch? Ist es Teil eines Fließtexts, vielleicht in einem politikwissenschaftlichen Aufsatz? -  So oder so sind wir hier im Grenzbereich zwischen Grammatik und Stilistik.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ist in etwa ein Gliederungspunkt einer Seminararbeit. Also gibt es das keine grundlegende Regel?

Comment: Es gibt keine *Grammatikvorschrift* dafür. Es ist eine stilistische Frage. In einer Kapitelüberschrift würdest du das zweite *der* eher weglassen. Man strebt nach Kürze und erlaubt sich dabei diese klitzekleine Abweichung von der peniblen grammatischen Korrektheit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das zweite »der« wird von der Grammatik nicht gefordert und ist (als Wortwiederholung auf engem Raum) auch stilistisch ungünstig. Ich würde es daher weglassen.

> Konflikt als Folge der Expansionspolitik und Aufrüstung Chinas

Sollte sich die Expansionspolitik wider Erwarten nicht auf China beziehen, müsste man den Text umformulieren, um vom Leser nicht missverstanden zu werden.

Comment: Ja, interessanter Gedanke. Wenn zuvor von der Expansionspolitik **Russlands** die Rede war, und man nun spricht von "Konflikt als Folge der Expansionspolitik [wir erinnern uns: Russlands] und **der** Aufrüstung Chinas", dann ist das *der* natürlich obligatorisch.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn in einer Aufzählung ein [Determinativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)) mehrfach vorkommt, genügt es, dieses Wort nur einmal anzugeben, unter der Voraussetzung, dass die aufgezählten Begriffe eine Einheit bilden.

Beispiel 1:

> 1. Ich fahre mit **meinem** Freund und **meinem** Arbeitskollegen Kurt nach München.
> 2. Ich fahre mit **meinem** Freund und Arbeitskollegen Kurt nach München.

Hier ist **Variante 2** der Vorzug zu geben, weil *Freund* und *Arbeitskollege* beide dieselbe Person (Kurt) bezeichnen. Kurt ist Freund und Arbeitskollege zugleich.

Beispiel 2:

> 1. Ich fahre mit **meinem** Freund Werner und **meinem** Arbeitskollegen Kurt nach München.
> 2. Ich fahre mit **meinem** Freund Werner und Arbeitskollegen Kurt nach München.

In dieser Aufzählung bilden Freund und Arbeitskollege keine Einheit. Sie bezeichnen zwei verschiedene Personen. Daher darf die zweite Instanz des Artikelworts *meinem* nicht weggelassen werden. **Variante 1** ist richtig.

---

> 1. Konflikt als Folge **der** Expansionspolitik und **der** Aufrüstung Chinas.
> 2. Konflikt als Folge **der** Expansionspolitik und Aufrüstung Chinas.

Hier sind sowohl die *Expansionspolitik* als auch die *Aufrüstung* Attribute desselben Staates (China). Es liegt also dieselbe Situation wie im Beispiel 1 vor, das heißt: Das Determinativ muss nur einmal im Satz stehen. Richtig ist **Variante 2**

Gegenbeispiel:

> 1. Konflikt als Folge **der** Expansionspolitik Russlands und **der** Aufrüstung Chinas.
> 2. Konflikt als Folge **der** Expansionspolitik Russlands und Aufrüstung Chinas.

In diesem Satz ist **Variante 1** richtig.

Comment: Wie ist es bei Aufzählungen, bei denen die einzelnen Wörter unterschiedliches Geschlecht haben? Z.B. "Konflikt als Folge der Expansionspolitik und des  Auftretens Chinas.". Kann hier das "des" weggelassen werden?

Comment: @IgorO.: Nein. Denn das ist ja nicht dasselbe Wort.

Comment: Aber sowohl die Expansionspolitik, als auch das Auftreten beziehen sich auf dasselbe Staat (China) wie in Ihrem letzten Beispiel? Bzw. ich sehe keinen Unterschied, zu dem Beispiel aus der ursprünglichen Frage. Der einzige Unterschied ist ja nur, dass sich die Artikel unterscheiden? Oder verstehe ich es falsch? :)

Comment: Nocheinmal: »der« und »des« sind zwei verschiedene Wörter. Hier kommt kein Wort mehrfach vor. Und daher kann man auch nichts weglassen. Um es anders zu formulieren: Der Unterschied ist, dass sich die Artikel unterscheiden. Wenn sie sich unterscheiden, sind sie nicht identisch, daher kann man keinen der beiden Artikel weglassen.

Comment: Danke für Ihre Antwort! Ich habe zuerst gedacht, dass Sie mit "zwei unterschiedlichen Wörtern" nicht die Artikel meinen.

Comment: @IgorO.: Ich habe im allerersten Satz recht klar betont, dass es um **Determinative** geht, und habe zur Sicherheit diesen Begriff auch mit dem einem Link zum entsprechenden Wikipedia-Artikel unterlegt. Auch in den Beispielen habe ich ausschließlich diese Determinative fett hervorgehoben. Die Wörter *»unterschiedlich«* oder *»Unterschied«* kommen in meiner Antwort kein einziges Mal vor.